# Nodemailer throws error on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, nodemailer

I'm trying to use the `nodemailer` package in my NodeJS app, which I have deployed on Azure. If I execute the app on my localhost everything works fine. If I execute it on Azure it throws the following error:

```
    Thu Jan 25 2018 09:03:31 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\nodemailer.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\api\apiAccount.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "passport-local-express4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "make test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:mjhea0/passport-local-express4.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "azure-storage": "^2.6.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "chai": "^1.8.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "debug": "^2.6.8",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-fileupload": "^0.3.0",
    "express-session": "^1.10.1",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "mocha": "^1.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.10.6",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "node-cache": "^4.1.1",
    "nodemailer": "*",
    "passport": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^1.3.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.3",
    "should": "^2.1.1",
    "xoauth2": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

If I navigate to the`node_modules` directory on Azure, `nodemailer` is a folder and all the necessary code is in there. If I run `node -v` on the Kudu console the NodeJS version is 8.9.0. The line, which is mentioned in the error message (apiAccount5:20) is:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

If I try to run `node app.js` in the Kudu console, there are no errors thrown.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the following line in `iisnode.yml` file:

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.9.0\node.exe"
```

However, you can verify the correct Node.js version running in your application by using [`process.version`](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.12/api/process.html#process_process_version) like this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('Hello from Azure running node version: ' + process.version + '</br>');
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```